# Removing characters from a printed variable

Tags: python

I have a variable which prints the below:

110,356,248.35 ZAR

How would I go about removing the "ZAR" as well as all the ",".

An excerpt of my code below:

```
IMPPEN36ONEPEF = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#product-UT td.portfolioProductContractFundHeaderValueRight"))).get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()
print(IMPPEN36ONEPEF)
```

I would like the output to be 110356248.35 but its printing as 110,356,248.35 ZAR.

Comment: `IMPPEN36ONEPEF = IMPPEN36ONEPEF.replace("ZAR", "").replace(",", "").strip()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.replace`:

```
>>> s = '110,356,248.35 ZAR'
>>> s.replace(',','').replace(' ZAR','')
'110356248.35'
>>>
```

Or use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '110,356,248.35 ZAR'
>>> re.sub('[A-Z, ]','',s)
'110356248.35'
>>>
```

Comment: @Saadiq Use it like: `print(IMPPEN36ONEPEF.replace(',','').replace(' ZAR',''))`, or `import re`, and next line `re.sub('[A-Z, ]','',IMPPEN36ONEPEF)`

Answer (score 1):

If `ZAR` is always at the end you can use

```
IMPPEN36ONEPEF = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#product-UT td.portfolioProductContractFundHeaderValueRight"))).get_attribute('innerHTML').replace(",","").strip("ZAR")

print(IMPPEN36ONEPEF)
```

Comment: hey thanks for your response, but unfortunately the output is worse now. Its returning with spaces in front as well             101590958.35 ZAR

Comment: It shouldn't. you use same code as mine? make sure you havn't added any spaces in `replace` or `strip`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for this

```py
import re

IMPPEN36ONEPEF = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#product-UT td.portfolioProductContractFundHeaderValueRight"))).get_attribute('innerHTML')

IMPPEN36ONEPEF = re.sub('[a-zA-Z, ]*', '', IMPPEN36ONEPEF)

print(IMPPEN36ONEPEF)
```

Output

```sh
110356248.35
```

Extend my regular expression if you need to remove additional stuff.

Comment: Hey I dont know how to incorporate this into my code without specifying the printed value (110,356,248.35 ZAR) first

Comment: @Saadiq, how about now? I edited it with using your code example